# Redox flow battery

Tags: electrochemistry

What is meant by decoupling of power and energy in context of redox flow battery? I understand that the electrolyte containing the active ions can be stored in tanks and that adds flexibility in scale up. But what does decoupling of power and energy mean in the context of redox flow battery.

Comment: Please explain ! Power and energy cannot be coupled, because they are different concepts. You cannot couple length and temperature, weight and time, concentration and height.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, by energy/power  decoupling is here meant the possibility of independent scaling up of the available sustained battery power and the possibly stored energy.

For normal batteries of electrochemical cells, regardless of their chemistry, scaling up increases both battery power and energy in more or less comparable rate.

But for redox flow batteries, like $\ce{V^2+/V^3+ + VO2+/VO^2+}$, there is possibility to scale up both power and energy independently.

Scaling up energy can be done by increasing the total volume of working solutions.

Scaling up power can be done by increasing the total active surface of electrodes.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the reasonable interpretation of what the OP wanted, so I will delete my comment in a couple of hours.